# Eeeek! Greatest hits page broken in beta sites on Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, greatest-hits

Expanding questions on the greatest hits page doesn't work properly on beta sites -- expansion is to the right instead of down.

See below:

[image]

Repro:

1. Go to `[betasite].stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits` ([this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), for example)
2. Pick a random question and click "show full question"
3. Observe how the question is expanded to the right instead of down

Reproducible on:

- Firefox 9.0.1 on Linux Mint Debian x64 (with and without addons)
- Firefox 11.0 on Ubuntu 12.01 beta x86 (with and without addons)
- Firefox 9.0 on Win7 x64 (with and without addons)

**Not** reproducible on:

- Chromium 16/17.0.`versionoftheday`, any platform
- Internet Explorer 9
- All non-beta sites (as far as I can tell)

Comment: Confirmed in Firefox 10.0.2 (Windows XP)

Comment: now it seems to work (10.0.2 on MacOS)

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Nope, still broken for me.

Comment: seems to work for me in FF11...

Comment: broken in 8.0.1 on Mac 10.6

Comment: Who uses firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the real bug is that we are even allowing for an ajax expand there, makes no sense imho.

It will be gone in the next build.