# Greatest Hits page isn't particularly great at maths

Tags: bug, status-completed, greatest-hits

The Greatest Hits page (like the [one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits)) displays 1000 items with a page size of 50, but has 21 pages:

[image: blank 21st page]

As a result, the last page is always empty and should just not be included.

Additionally, anonymous users are presented with a JavaScript error on any page number, as `answer-loader.js` attempts to call `StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.init()` which is undefined for them. I'm not entirely sure what that script does off-hand, but might be remnants of the functionality removed in the fix for [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123478/eeeek-greatest-hits-page-broken-in-beta-sites-on-firefox)?

Comment: yes ... both my bugs ...

Comment: This *is* actually a bug, right? Not an artifact of ignored tags and client-side filtering? Or is that still a bug?

Comment: @waffles I'm willing to randomly pick another dev from the Wheel of Blame if you want to deny all responsibility. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I blame syrup ... waffles's evil twin .... both will be fixed in the next deploy